# which client is best HttpURLConnection or HttpClient in android?

Tags: php, android, json, web-services

I am totally confused which one is better for calling php webservice using Restful Protocol.I 
did Used both API(HttpClient and HttpURLConnection) for calling webservice.

What happen when calling a webservice using **HttpClient**

- On Froyo its working perfectly(on localhost and server).
- On JellyBean Working but after some time is gone then not working
- HttpClient is working fine on localhost but problem with calling werbservice on server.

What happen when calling a webservice using **HttpURLConnection**

- On Froyo not working properly(on localhost)
- the second point is same as second point of HttpClient
- I can not redirect the php webservice page to another php page.

When i calling webservice abc.php(on localhost and server) and from here i redirect to another page like xyz.php.  from xyz.php actually return data to the android project in json form but what happen when i using HttpClient is working fine but this redirection not work with HttpURLConnection.

HttpClient code

```
//calling the webservice using AsyncTask
public String makeHttpReqToSrvr(String url,String requestType,List<NameValuePair> params) {

    HttpEntity httpEntity=null;
    HttpResponse httpResp = null;

    try {

        if (requestType == "GET") {

            //connection time out
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeout1 = 1000*8;
                int timeout2 = 1000*8;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeout1);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeout2);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            String paramString =URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url+"?"+paramString);
            httpResp = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            httpEntity = httpResp.getEntity();

        }
        if (requestType == "POST") {
            // connection time out
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeout1 = 1000*8;
                int timeout2 = 1000*8;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeout1);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeout2);

            HttpClient  httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            httpResp = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            httpEntity = httpResp.getEntity();

        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    // -- End and Start read the data using bufferreader
    try {
        if(httpEntity != null)
            json = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            json = strBuilder.toString();
                Log.v("JSON", "data"+json);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return json;
}
```

HttpURLConnection code

```
public String makeHttpReqToSrvr(String url,String requestType,List<NameValuePair> params) {

    try {
        URL urlPath= null;
        String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");

        if (requestType == "GET") {
            urlPath = new URL(url+"?"+paramString);
        }
        if (requestType == "POST") {
            urlPath = new URL(url);
        }

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlPath.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000); 
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000); 
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        if (requestType == "GET") {
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        }
        if (requestType == "POST") {
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        }
        //send the data to the server using post
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(paramString);
        dos.flush();

        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();

        is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        json = readIt(is);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
                dos.close();
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    return json;
```

} 

please anybody suggest me if any wrong with above code and tell me perfect way to call 
webservice. I tried lot but not achive my goal. If you do not understand above question so please
ask me.

Apache HTTP client has fewer bugs on Eclair and Froyo. It is the best choice for these releases.

google recommend using HttpURLConnection for applications targeted at Gingerbread and higher
Prior to Froyo, HttpURLConnection had some frustrating bugs. then what about Froyo. My apps 
run on froyo and higher versoin.

Which client is best?

Any help will be of great use.Thank you.

Comment: when are you calling these functions?! if it isnt in `asyncTask` then this your problem. because in earlier versions you could use httpClient without a thread but in 4.0 you require to use `asynctask`

Comment: i used AsyncTask in my entire apps. just i am calling makeHttpReqToSrvr method from doInBackground method from activity. I know about AsyncTask. I used both client class for check

Answer (score 1):

HttpUrlConnection is not good as told by android google engineer in 2010 IO conferences.
According to them this create adverse effect on network.
ref: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

use httpclient or Androidhttpclient

Best of luck

Comment: but on this url google recommend use HttpURLConnection. but HttpClient having the number of problem.

Comment: Please go throw mr Virgil Dobjanschi's lecture. In this he recommend apache httpclient rather java httpurlconnection.

I use httpclient most of the time .

Comment: sorry this is url for google recommend http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Comment: what you need to do ? file uploading downloading or simple data sharing ?

Comment: I think you should choose httpclient.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [OKHTTP](https://github.com/square/okhttp) from Square. Check out the github page [here](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

Comment: Is OKHTTP work on all version of android? did you used OKHHTTP successfully?

Comment: Is OKHTTP is open source?

Comment: yes its open source (Apache 2.0) - see the github page for more info. I have used it on a few production projects successfully - I prefer using it compared to `HttpUrlConnection` as you wont get any (or as many) platform specific bugs as its an external lib. It implements the `HttpUrlConnection` interface also

Comment: Thanks Dori. I will use in my apps.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously [Google changed their mind](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html).

HttpClient and AndroidHttpClient should only be used for FROYO and older.

Starting with GINGERBREAD it is recommended to use `HttpUrlConnection`.

I followed their recommendation and after a very short time of using HUC (aka. HttpUrlConnection) natively, I wrote a small library (~12kb jar) which is much easier to use.

The library is called [DavidWebb](https://github.com/hgoebl/DavidWebb) and there you can find many links to other HTTP/REST libraries especially for Android.